# Azure DS_V2 vs FS Series comparison

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I am trying to decide on using the FS series which is cheaper compared to the DS_V2 series.  They look exactly the same except the local SSD is smaller in the FS series.

My question is if I am running a high performance, high load web server does the smaller local SSD a big issue in terms of the price?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-sizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mian difference between DS and FS series VM, less local SSD and reduced amount of memory per core, this obviously makes the F series cheaper. So whether this is an issue is really going to depend on your work load.

For the SSD size, this is only going to impact you if your using the local SSD for paging or similar temporary operations. The D and F series performance when using premium storage for non-temporary disks is exactly the same, so it's only the temporary disk that is an issue.

For memory, you need to look at your applications memory profile and determine if you can cope with the lower amount of memory or not.

As has been mentioned, you can easily change between FS and DS, so your best bet is to do some performance testing with your application.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is if I am running a high performance, high load web
>   server does the smaller local SSD a big issue in terms of the price?

The local SSD is used to save the system paging file.
For example: If your workflow involves getting content from the blob, processing it and storing it back to the blob then you could download content to the temporary storage, process the content, **then** take the processed content and save it back to the blob.

If your web does not have a lot of data written, I think **local SSD** will not affect performance.

By the way, we should check the Max disk throughput, if you chose **standard_F1**, the max IOPS is **3000**, if you choose **standard_DS1_v2**, the max IOPS is **4000**.

Also, after the VM deployed, we can change the size of your VM based on the needs for CPU, Network or disk performance(**resize**).

Comment: FS not F, they are the same in IOPS so I would remove that comment.  I know you can resize it.  The local SSD is that automatic or do you have to control how you use it?

Comment: I believe I dont use the SSD at all as I see it as an attached drive.  I may use it in the future but I don't need that much space so I think the FS series will work just fine with the lower SSD.